# Software back button android

Tags: java, android, button, back

I need a back button with same functionality as default back button of device but inside of app.

Comment: It's really a poorly-worded question, but if all you need to do is go "back" from an activity, add a button and invoke `finish()` when it's clicked. Hard to believe that the documentation didn't tell you this.

Comment: You can emulate a back press by calling [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

Comment: Another common approach is to take advantage of the `ActionBar` and their navigation controls.  This is another accepted approach for navigation internally outside the back button built into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android activities are stored in the activity stack. You can go back by just finishing the current activity:

add an `onClick` listener to your button in the activity xml like this:

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

then create a method in your activity with the same name you specified in the xml

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     finish()
 }
```

You can read more in the [docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: eduardo thank you for your answer and when i add that code it tells me that cannot resolve setOnClickListener and v

Comment: did you copy and paste ? you need to add your button id instead of R.id.buttonId

Comment: thank you it worked with my app.. but i have another question and if you could answer it i wouldnt post it.. i buy app on one site app works fine but now i wanted to add back button code and when i open java file it starts showing errors  cannot resolve symbol and shows different symbols  before i opened java file everything was fine..  i haven't changed anything. what could be problem?

Comment: i accepted it but can't upvote need 15 reputation and im new user

Comment: I dont understand the question, ask a new one and add a screen shot or something, and give me a link. Make it as simple, and straight forward as possible so you could get up voted and get points.

Comment: i have posted question. but i was unable to add screenshot don't have enough points

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955787/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbols